# How make Custom Processor follow failure relationship

Tags: apache-nifi

A newbie question.
I presume that the flow from a Processor will follow a failure relationship if there is some failure in processing the FlowFile ? 
If I have a custom Processor and I want the failure relationship to be followed, eg if an Oauth token does not contain a valid role, how do I do this in the code ? Do I just throw an exception from the onTrigger method, and if so, does it need to be any particular exception ?
Thanks very much in advance.
pxm

Comment: Failure relationship is the same as success. You have to transfer flow file to it in the same way as transferring to other relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways to handle an error...

1) Throw an exception out of onTrigger - this rolls back the session for the given execution of onTigger, which puts any flow files back in the incoming queue to be tried again.

2) Transfer a flow file to a failure relationship - you have to handle this yourself by catching any expected errors and transferring the flow file to the desired relationship, the same as you would for transferring to success.